# codigo aparecendo como texto

Tags: php, mysql

estou tentando inserir uma tabela mas quando eu adiciono ela, fica aparecendo meu o código como se fosse um texto, mas funciona lol.

Alguém sabe oq tem de errado no meu código que nao consigo encontrar?

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'mysql_connect.php';
include 'season_info.php';

if ($_SESSION['HoopsUser'] != NULL)
{
    if (isset($_GET['Sort']))
        {
            $sort = $_GET['Sort'];
            if ($sort == 'Age')
            {
                $age = 'Age_Asc';
            }
            else
            {
                $age = 'Age';
            }
        }

        if (isset($_GET['Position']))
        {
            $position = $_GET['Position'];
            $and = '&Position='.$position.'';
            {
                if ($position == 'Draft')
                {       
                    $and = '&Position='.$position.'';
                }
                else if ($position == 'FA')
                {       
                    $and = '&Position='.$position.'';
                }
                else if ($position == 'Prev')
                {       

                }
                else if ($position == 1)
                {



                }

                else if ($position == 2)

                {



                }

                else if ($position == 3)

                {



                }

                else if ($position == 4)

                {


                }

                else if ($position == 5)

                {



                }

            }

        }

        else

        {



        }

        echo '


            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>' . "\n";



    $sql = 'SELECT *, freeagencycoach.ID AS ID FROM freeagencycoach INNER JOIN Staff ON freeagencycoach.Player = Staff.ID WHERE CurrentTeam = 0 AND User = \''.$_SESSION['HoopsUser'].'\' AND Year = '.$year.' AND Years > 0 AND Amount > 0';

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if ($count > 0)

    {

        echo '

        <table class="middle2" cellpadding="0">

            <tr>

                <td width="800" valign="top" align="center">

                    <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="1" style="border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#909090">

                    <tr class="stat_header">

                        <td align="left" colspan="25" style="padding-left:6px">Current Offers</td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr class="header">

                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:4px">PLAYER</td>

                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:4px">OFFER</td>

                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px">CANCEL</td>

                    </tr>' . "\n";

    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

    {

        $player = '<a href="player.php?ID='.$row['Player'].'" class="link">' . $row['Name'] . '</a>';

        if (0 == ($x++ & 1)) { $sClass = 'odd'; } else { $sClass = 'even'; }



        $sql2 = 'SELECT Player, Pos FROM ContractRequests WHERE ID = '.$row['Player'].'';

        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))

        {

            $player = '<a href="player.php?ID='.$row['Player'].'" class="link">' . $row2['Player'] . '</a>, ' . $row2['Pos'];

        }



        if ($row['Years'] == 99)

        {

            $contract = 'Max offer';

        }

        else if ($row['Amount'] == 0) {

            $contract = 'Min offer';

        }

        else

        {

            $contract = '&#36;'.number_format($row['Amount']).'/'.$row['Years'].' yr(s)';

        }



        echo '          <tr class="'.$sClass.'">

                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:4px">'.$player.'</td>

                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:4px">'.$contract.'</td>

                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:4px;padding-right:4px"><a href="freeagency_withdraw.php?Offer='.$row['ID'].'" class="link">Withdraw</a></td>

                    </tr>' . "\n";

    }

    if ($count > 0)

    {

        echo '

                    </table>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>' . "\n";

    }











    if (isset($_GET['Position']))

    {

        if ($_GET['Position'] == 'Prev') {

            $prev_year = $year - 1;

            $where = 'INNER JOIN SeasonStats ON SeasonStats.ID = Player.ID WHERE SeasonStats.Season = '.$prev_year.' AND SeasonStats.Team = \''.$_SESSION['HoopsTeam'].'\' AND CurrentTeam = \'FA\'';

        } else {

            $where = 'WHERE CurrentTeam = \'FA\' AND PositionNumber = '.$_GET['Position'].'';

        }

    }

    else

    {

        $where = 'WHERE CurrentTeam = \'FA\'';

    }



    if (isset($_GET['Sort']))

    {

        $sort = $_GET['Sort'];

        if ($sort == 'Age_Asc')

        {

            $sort = 'Player.Age';

            $by = '';

        }

        else if ($sort == 'FutureRating')

        {

            $sort = 'FutureRating';

            $by = '';

        }

        else if ($sort == 'Age')

        {

            $sort = 'Player.Age';

            $by = 'DESC';

        }

        else

        {

            $by = 'DESC';

        }

    }

    else

    {

        $sort = 'Overall';

        $by = 'DESC';

    }




    {

        $rank++;

        $name = $row['FirstName'] . ". " . $row['LastName'];

        $id = $row['ID'];

        $team = '<a href="clubhouse.php?Team='.$row['Abbr'].'" class="link">'.$row['Abbr'].'</a>';

        $pos = $row['PositionNumber'];

        if ($row['PositionNumber'] == 1) { $pos = 'C'; } else if ($row['PositionNumber'] == 2) { $pos = 'PF'; }

        else if ($row['PositionNumber'] == 3) { $pos = 'SF'; } else if ($row['PositionNumber'] == 4) { $pos = 'SG'; }

        else if ($row['PositionNumber'] == 5) { $pos = 'PG'; }

        $age = $row['Age'];

        $exp = $row['Experience'];

        $ovr = number_format($row['Overall'],0);

        $inches = $row['Height'];

        $ft = floor($inches/12);

        $in = $inches % 12;

        $ht = $ft . '\'' . $in . '"'; 

        $wt = $row['Weight'];

        $ins = $row['InsideScoring'];

        $jps = $row['JumpShot'];

        $ft = $row['FreeThrowShot'];

        $tp = $row['ThreePointShot'];

        $pas = $row['Passing'];

        $hnd = $row['Handling'];

        $orb = $row['OffensiveRebounding'];

        $drb = $row['DefensiveRebounding'];

        $psd = $row['PostDefense'];

        $prd = $row['PerimeterDefense'];

        $stl = $row['Stealing'];

        $blk = $row['ShotBlocking'];

        $jmp = $row['Jumping'];

        $qkn = $row['Quickness'];

        $sth = $row['Strength'];

        $sta = $row['Stamina'];

        $ovr = number_format($row['Overall'],0);

        $fut = $row['FutureRating'];



        if ($row['BirdYears'] >= 3 && $_GET['Position'] == 'Prev') {

            $bird_rights = '<sup><font style="font-size:8px;font-family:Verdana;color:#009900">BIRD</font></sup>';

        } else {

            $bird_rights = '';

        }







        if ($sort == 'Player.Age') { $class1 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Overall') { $class2 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'InsideScoring') { $class3 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'JumpShot') { $class4 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'FreeThrowShot') { $class5 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'ThreePointShot') { $class6 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Handling') { $class7 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Passing') { $class8 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'OffensiveRebounding') { $class9 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'DefensiveRebounding') { $class10 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'PostDefense') { $class11 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'PerimeterDefense') { $class12 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Stealing') { $class13 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'ShotBlocking') { $class14 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Quickness') { $class15 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Strength') { $class16 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Jumping') { $class17 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }

        if ($sort == 'Stamina') { $class18 = ' class="sort_bold"'; }



        // InsideScoring*0.3+JumpShot*0.09+ThreePointShot*1.5+Handling*0.2+Passing*2+OffensiveRebounding*4+DefensiveRebounding*4+PostDefense+PerimeterDefense*3+Stealing+ShotBlocking*0.8+Quickness*0.7+Jumping*0.5+Strength



        if (0 == ($i++ & 1)) { $sClass = 'odd'; }

        else { $sClass = 'even'; }



        if ($sort == 'Player.Age')

        {

            $sort = 'Age';

        }



        if ($row[''.$sort.''] != $last_stat)

        {

            $last_stat = $row[''.$sort.''];

            $rank = $i;

        }

        else

        {

            $rank = ' ';

        }



        echo '              <tr class="'.$sClass.'">



                    </tr>';



        if ($i % 20 == 0 && $i != 100 && $i != 250)

        {

            echo '

                    <tr class="header">

                        <td align="left" style="padding-left:4px">PLAYER</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">AGE</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">EXP</td>

                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">CUR</td>

                        <td align="center" style="padding-left:2px;padding-right:2px">POT</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">OVR</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">INS</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">JPS</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">FT</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">3PS</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">HND</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">PAS</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">ORB</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">DRB</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">PSD</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">PRD</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">STL</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">BLK</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">QKN</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">STR</td>

                        <td align="right" style="padding-right:4px">JMP</td>

                    </tr>';

        }

    }

    echo '

                    <tr>



                    </tr>

                </table>

                </form>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>';



    if ($_SESSION['HoopsUser'] == 'admin') {

        echo $sql;

    }




}

else

{

    $redirect = urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=login.php?location=$redirect\">";

    echo '

    <table class="middle3">

        <tr>

            <td>

                <table class="maintop">

                    <tr>

                        <td><font class="playersubhead">Access Restricted</font></td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <table class="middle2">

        <tr>

            <td width="800" valign="top" align="center">

                <table width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="1">

                    <tr class="odd">

                        <td colspan="20" align="left" style="padding-left:6px">You must be logged in to access this page!</td>

                    </tr>

                </table>

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <br>

    ';
}
```

Comment: você tem print do problema ocorrido?

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/tCz5k2KR/print.png

Comment: Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro.

Comment: Se não gosta de documentar seus códigos beleza. Pelo menos dá um destaque quando inserir código de teste senão acontece isso, você acaba esquecendo no código um fragmento de teste que por ventura pode a vir chegar ao ambiente de produção e gerar uma surpresa desagradável para seu cliente.

Answer (score 1):

Maycon, seu código tem um trecho que exibe a query caso o usuário seja o admin:

```
if ($_SESSION['HoopsUser'] == 'admin') {

    echo $sql;

}
```

Acredito que esse seja o motivo de exibir o código no HTML, remova ou comente esse trecho e veja o resultado.